# Store shipping plugin …

Tags: expresso-store, add-on-development, plugin

Does anybody have a sample shipping plugin for Store 2?
The only one I have is for 1.5 and the documentation isn't very helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Cole

Answer (score 1):

(I'm with [Vector](https://www.vectormediagroup.com), the people behind Expresso Store, but this is just something I made quickly and shouldn't be considered "official advice")

Here's a sample to get you started:

```
<?php

/*
** The below is pseudo-code just meant to show how to write a
** shipping extension for Expresso Store 2, 3, or 4. It shouldn't
** be used as-is in a production environment.
*/

if (defined('PATH_THIRD')) {
    require PATH_THIRD.'store/autoload.php';
}

use Store\Exception\ShippingException;
use Store\Model\Order;
use Store\Model\OrderShippingMethod;

class Store_sample_shipping_ext
{

    public $hooks = array('store_order_shipping_methods');
    public $settings = array();

    public function __construct($settings = array())
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function store_order_shipping_methods(Order $order, array $methods)
    {

        if (ee()->extensions->last_call !== false) {
            $methods = ee()->extensions->last_call;
        }

        // If you have logic that decides if your method should be used or not,
        // you can always just return the existing $methods

        if (!$this->should_be_active()) {
            return $methods;
        }

        // You'd do logic here to calculate your actual shipping methods and costs.
        // Once you've determined that, add them to the $methods array. You can add
        // more than one. The format for each one is this:

        $option = new OrderShippingMethod;
        $option->id = __CLASS__.':'.'some identifier, if you add more than one';
        $option->name = $this->clean_str('A friendly name');
        $option->class = __CLASS__;
        $option->amount = '12.34';

        $methods[$option->id] = $option;

        // If you want to sort, for example by cheapest first
        uasort($methods, function($a, $b) {
            return $a->amount - $b->amount;
        });

        return $methods;
    }

    protected function clean_str($str)
    {
        return strip_tags(str_replace('&reg;', '', html_entity_decode($str)));
    }

    public function activate_extension()
    {
        foreach ($this->hooks as $hook) {
             $data = array( 'class'     =>  __CLASS__,
                            'method'    =>  $hook,
                            'hook'      =>  $hook,
                            'settings'  =>  serialize($this->settings),
                            'priority'  =>  10,
                            'version'   =>  $this->version,
                            'enabled'   =>  'y'
                );

            // insert in database
            ee()->db->insert('exp_extensions', $data);
        }
    }

    public function disable_extension()
    {
        ee()->db->where('class', __CLASS__);
        ee()->db->delete('exp_extensions');
    }

}
```

Comment: Many thanks Matt - is there a way to automatically apply a custom shipping method in the checkout and cart calculations or does it have to be applied? Managed to work way round it with a shipping method hidden field in the template/checkout form but be good to have it applied without needing to specify. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @ColeHenley You can potentially make that the only option, but if your hidden field is working for you might just be worth sticking with it!